# I would like to execute a file.py merely by stating "file" rather than "python file.py"

Tags: python, permissions

I have added the following to my file:

```
chmod +x /home/me/file.py (as well as tried chmod a+x) 
#!/tps/bin/env python (I also tried #!/usr/bin/env python but which python returns /tps/bin/python)
```

I get permission denied when I execute this. 
And from other instances of this question for troubleshooting: "umask" returns 22 and "ls -l file.py" returns -rw-r--r--. I am using mac OS X El Capitan but I'm running this remotely on a linux machine.
I would like this file to be executable by people other than me as well.
Thanks all

Comment: Your title as well as your question are unclear, @stackofpancakes. I don't quite understand it. Please reformulate, and provide relevant informations; like the OS you're using for example. Cheers!

Comment: `chmod +x` should have done the trick. Maybe, the file system restricts files to be non-executable? I would use the recommended shebang version `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of a system specific path, which makes the script less portable.

Comment: @Oleiade I've made some changes. My main purpose here is to not require a user to have to type "python file.py" and they could instead execute the file simply with "file". I may have made this unintentionally obtuse because when looking this up I've seen similar issues but their solutions didn't seem to work for me so I've tried to include all that they have suggested in the past.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I agree I'd like this to remain portable. As for the file system restricting to non-executables, I'm unsure how to troubleshoot or proceed in that case. Thanks

Comment: @stackofpancakes I agree, the "permission denied" message is not very helpful but I had a similar case earlier this week and for me it was a partition being mounted with the no-executable flag, so you might want to check that.